# I keep getting a server error 500 after adding syntactically correct code to .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

thanks for taking a look at my question.

I have a WordPress instance installed in the root directory and another one in a subdirectoy called **/en** *(subdirectory site url looks like www.mysite.com/en)* so basically the root directory has an instace of WP and then in that same root directory I created subdirectory called **/en** with another instance of WP.

in order to avoid 404 errors I appropriately changed the .htaccess in the subdirectory to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I visit the site that is in subdirectory, it gives me the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

**Please Help!**

Comment: **RewriteRule ^index\.php  [L]** should be **RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]** notice the missing argument **-**

Comment: @starkeen it's clearly not missing the dash.

Comment: Do you have access to Apache's error log? There should be more details about the `500` error there. Often this is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but could be different on your server's configuration. If it's a shared hosting account, some hosts provide the error log in their control panel.

Comment: Also, try deleting and re-typing the `-` in the line `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`, because it looks like a long dash ("em-dash") rather than a hyphen. That can happen when copying & pasting dashes sometimes, especially if copying the code from a web page. (WordPress converts single hyphens into en-dashes, when displaying post content, and some other CMS software might as well.)